# Display a custom taxonomy name in Timber for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I got a custom taxonomy of events called "typology".

Taxonomy :
slug : typology
name : Typologies
- type 1
- type 2
- type 3

I created a dynamic selector that displays each type in order to filter a list of post based on that specific taxonomy.

This part is OK with :

```
$context['terms-typology'] = Timber::get_terms('typology');
```

and in twig

```
<select>
  {% for term in typology %}
     <option value="{{ term }}">{{ term }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

But i would like to add a first option (selected by default) which would be an unfiltered option and where the text should be : "All Typologies".

I tried to add this option and get back the parent {{ term.name }}

I tried to pass it in the context with another line :

```
$context['term'] = new Timber\Term('typology');
```

And use

```
<option selected value="{{ term.name }}">All {{ term.name }}</option>
```

I've tried many other things. But I just don't manage to do it and I don't get it.

Comment: `All Typologies` is not in the database? Then you could add it before the loop

Comment: I added the "option" before my loop.

My problem is that it don't print the name "Typologies" at all. Don't print anything. Is my call wrong ?

Comment: No you didn't. `new Timber\Term('typology');` will do nothing but trying to the fetch the `Term` with id `typology` out of the database, which is non-existent. See the [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-term/#__construct). You could use `<option value="-1" {{ term_id|default == -1 ? ' selected' }}>All Typologies</option>`